# Visual Studio ASP.NET unknown user name or bad password

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, iis

I am trying to debug an asp.net website on a remote IIS server.

When I debug the project, I get the error `unknown user name or bad password`.

After sniffing with wireshark, he is using a username that doesn't exist on my machine.

Where can you select which user it uses to do the remote debugging?

Answer (score 0):

The remote debugging tool (msvsmon.exe) doesn't give you the option to select a user when you begin the debugging session in VS; it must already be configured to allow the account to debug when the session is started.

You can do this by opening msvsmon on the target system, selecting Tools -> Permissions, and adding the necessary user account(s).

From the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y5b4b4f(v=vs.100).aspx) regarding how to configure user accounts for remote debugging across domains (which I also found useful setting up debugging from a domain system to a workgroup system):

> To connect to msvsmon, you must run Visual Studio under the same user account as msvsmon or under an administrator account. (You can also configure msvsmon to accept connections from other users.)
>
> Visual Studio accepts connections from msvsmon if msvsmon is running as a user who can be authenticated on the Visual Studio computer. (The user must have a local account on the Visual Studio computer.)

If both systems are in the same domain, this makes it a little easier:

1. Add a user account to the domain for this purpose (or use an existing domain account)
2. Add the domain user account to both systems
3. Configure msvsmon.exe to allow this user account to debug
4. Start your VS debugging session under this user account.